# Get sold items, ordered by purchases, in the last week

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Tables.

The first table stores the products.

```
id I Product Name
1  I Apple
2  I Bread
3  I Butter
... Many more
```

The second table stores the overall purchases with a date

```
product_id I purchasedoverall I date
1          I 2                I 1.2.14 
1          I 10               I 3.2.14
3          I 3                I 4.2.14
... Many more
```

Attention: In the example, at 1.2.14 2 apples where sold, at 3.2.14 8 more apples, so there are 10 stored in purchasedoverall.

What I want from the Database is: 
Give me the products purchased in the last week, ordered by how many items where bought IN THE LAST WEEK.

Until now, I do it this (bad) way:

1. I get all products

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM products
   ```

Store them in an array

1. I iterate over the array to get the purchased count in the last week

   ```sql
   SELECT MAX(c.purchasedoverall)-MIN(c.purchasedoverall) as purchased
   FROM products as a, puchased as c
   WHERE c.product_id = {product-id from the array}
         AND c.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
   ORDER BY c.date
   ```
2. I combine the arrays an sort them

My question: Can I do this with one MySQL-Query?

Comment: why are you storing the number of items "purchased overall" rather than simply "number purchased"?!  if your second table had "number purchased" it would be a very simple matter indeed!!

Comment: I know. Unfortunatelly another script stores which i cannot access - and did it a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pr.name` is unique:

```
   SELECT pr.name, 
          COALESCE(MAX(pu.purchasedoverall)-MIN(pu.purchasedoverall),0) purchased
     FROM products pr
LEFT JOIN purchased pu
       ON pu.product_id = pr.id
      AND pu.date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
 GROUP BY pr.name
 ORDER BY purchased DESC, pr.name
```

But as pointed out in the comments you should really be storing data at the resolution that you need it, not performing complex queries to enhance the resolution..

Whatever the difficulties of obtaining the data structure and the code associated, it is almost certainly much easier to refactor this than build a system atop a flawed design.

Comment: I know, I know. Maybe I have to do some talks. Thanks for your answer, which works but ist very slow. (Never heard about COALESCE, so I learned something about mysql..)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.product_name, MAX(c.purchasedoverall)-MIN(c.purchasedoverall) as total_purchased
FROM products a
    left join puchased c
    ON c.product_id=a.id
    AND c.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
group by a.id
ORDER BY total_purchased;
```

Comment: Looks good, but is even slower than the first answer - makes the server freeze...

Comment: Make sure you have indexes in your tables on c.product_id,  a.id and c.date.  Also.  Run the above querry with explain keyword at the front and post the results here.